# AspxCombox binding to a datasource

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a Devexpress `ASPxComboBox` which is bound to the `Users` table. On a page in another Project there is a field `EnteredBy`. I want to somehow make the `ASPxComboBox` be able to show the name that saved the user.

Comment: I guess that the table Users is a Database table. Then both projects share the data from a single point. What is your problem here. What does the combobox now show? Please add more information, as the question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ComboBox` control shows objects according to their `ToString()` property. If you want to print something in particular, you have to override the `ToString()` property of the binding objects.

Comment: Thanks Guys ,It was my mystake,I figured it out.I was going in wrong direction.